# Getting Variable accessing error after upgrading the Python and Robot framework version

Tags: robotframework

Below mentioned script has been worked in old python (2.7.x) and Robotframework version . 
The same code is not being worked ,after upgrading the python version from 2.7 to 3.7.2 and the robot version to 3.1.1.

I'm getting this error while executing script:

> **Variable '${var}' is string, not list or dictionary, and thus
>   accessing item '${var}' from it is not possible.**

Code :

```
${loc}   xpath=(//*[contains(@class,"c3-legend-item ")])

: FOR    ${row}    IN RANGE    1        ${Count}
\    ${Exp_Name} =    Get Text    ${loc}[${row}]    
\   Log    ${Exp_Name}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In robot version 3.1 there was a backwards-incompatible change. From the [release notes](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/rf-3.1.rst#square-brackets-after-variable-like-var-xxx-is-considered-item-access):

> **Square brackets after variable like ${var}[xxx] is considered item access**
>
> Syntax like ${var}[xxx] is now considered variable item access (#2601), not variable ${var} followed by a literal string [xxx]. If the latter is desired, escaping like ${var}[xxx] is needed.

In your specific case you're using `${loc}[${row}]`, where you're expecting `[${row}]` to be appended to `${loc}`. In 3.1 robot thinks that `[${row}]` is an index into `${loc}`.

The fix, as suggested in the release notes, is to escape the opening square bracket:

```
\    ${Exp_Name} =    Get Text    ${loc}\[${row}]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use catenate to build dynamic xpath.** This will work for you.

```
${loc}   xpath=(//*[contains(@class,"c3-legend-item ")])

: FOR    ${row}    IN RANGE    1        ${Count}

\    ${dynamic_xpath}=    Catenate    SEPARATOR=    ${loc}    [${row}]

\    ${Exp_Name} =    Get Text    ${dynamic_xpath}
```